# Linux distro for office/movies, Pentium 32bit, 1GiB memory

Tags: linux-distribution, office

I have the following machine:

- LG Electronics Notebook
- width: 32 bits
- Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 1.86GHz
  -memory size: 1GiB

Please let me know if you need more information.

I want to try out Linux as I've heard many a good thing about it. I'm however quite overwhelmed with all of the different distros out there.

I would like to avoid going through distro after distro trying to find one that will work for me and would therefore like to get advice from the community about what will work for my machine first.

I want to use it in an office environment, creating and printing documents in PDF and something similar to Word.

I'd also like to watch movies and listen to music from time to time. Games is not a big issue.

I'd also like to connect the computer to my home windows network to enable file sharing etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should give [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/about/) a try ... Here is a quote from that link:

> Lubuntu is a faster, more lightweight and energy saving, official flavour of Ubuntu using LXDE, the Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment.
>
> Lubuntu is designed to be fast and easy to use. It has lots of applications for every daily need, while keeping your system light and responsive, being it ideal not only for old computers and netbooks, but for newer computers too making them lightening fast.