# Maintained Linux distribution for 32-bit

Tags: linux-distribution, 32-bit

For an old laptop (2GHz, 1GB RAM) I am looking for such a Linux distribution:

- Supports **32-bit** processors, and has not announced that they will phase out 32-bit support.
- Is **maintained** (please link to the bug tracker, it must show discussions within the last month).
- Contains this software:

  - Secure **web browser** that can display modern websites.
  - Japanese **IME**.
- Receives security updates. For instance if an exploit is found in the web browser, it gets updated by the distribution itself, it does not require me to download and install a new version manually.

Non-solutions:

- Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Peppermint are not solutions because they are planning to phase out 32-bit support.
- LXLE is not a solution because it has not had any developer discussion within a month.

*([similar question but geared towards office rather than web browsing and security](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51118/linux-distro-for-office-movies-pentium-32bit-1gib-memory))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian's a good option. It has *fantastically* long update cycles, with the current version, [debian buster officially supported until 2026](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS). While its conservative in terms of package availability, I do believe security updates are prompt.

[Japanese IME](https://wiki.debian.org/JapaneseEnvironmentE) seems supported

[Firefox](https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/firefox/download) still seems to have 32 bit support as of May 2021. The version debian has now tallies with the current version number on FF's page (88.0 on the date of this answer). There's a chromium package as well but I am unable to verify if its the latest.